# How to terminate springboot application programmatically on cloud foundry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, system.exit

I need to terminate a springboot function programmatically with something like System.exit(-1); when running.

When I ran the app on my laptop, it could terminate at where I put "System.exit(-1);", but when I packaged it and ran it on cloud foundry, it just ignored the "System.exit(-1);" and keep running.

Is there anyway to terminate the app programmatically when it runs on cloud foundry?

Comment: Termination on CF means shutting down the instance.

Comment: @duffymo how to do that programmatically

Comment: What likely happened is that when you called `System.exit()` the process exited, CF noticed and restarted your app instance. That can happen very quick, so it's easy to not notice when it does happen. That's what it is supposed to do since the default web process on CF is designed to run forever. If you have a process that is not designed to run forever, you should run it as a task instead. `cf run-task`. A task can run for a period of time and exit, it won't be restarted.